# what is the best way to pass a string between views

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to pass a string to a "form" page template and then post the form and redirect to the previous  page by using the string that I have sent. The reason that I want to do it is to prevent the POST form issue of staying in the page after POST.

I created this get :

```
GET    /form/:page                               controllers.Pages.form(page)
```

and the controller look like that

```
public static Result form(String page) {          
    return ok(form.render(userForm),page);
}
```

and I'm trying to route like that :

```
<a href="@routes.Pages.form(page)" class="btn btn-info">send </a>
```

What is your preferred way to pass parameters between views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too am new to play but I see a few issues

Firstly, your routes file should be

```
GET    /form/:page                        controllers.Pages.form(page: String)
```

and in the controller Pages,

```
public static Result form(String page) {          
    return ok(form.render(userForm,page)); //Not ok(form.render(userForm),page)
}
```

finally in the view,

```
@(page :String)

<a href="@routes.Pages.form(page)" class="btn btn-info">send </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example just call:

```
<a href="@controllers.routes.Pages.form(page)" class="btn btn-info">send </a>
```

or

```
<a href="/form/@page" class="btn btn-info">send </a>
```

And this a should not be inside html form tag.

To be sure check with firebug, that your browser sends GET

Comment: Is page defined? You should define variable page `@(page:String)` or in other way.